# Responsive columns in Bootstrap with main column in the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Bootstrap to have this configuration

[image: configuration]

This needs to be responsive like the image shows. I tried this code but block 2 is not centered in the page

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 800px; margin-top: 20px; max-width:800px;position:relative" >
    <div class="col" style="top:420px;background: white; z-index:100;position:fixed; width: 194px;">
                
                   block 1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
              block 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I need block 1 on the left to follow as I scroll up and down the page

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you mean center the content of the bloc 2?

Comment: @Hamza no center bloc 2

Comment: @Elikill58 I don't understand

Comment: Check [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match) and you will understand ;)

Comment: @Elikill58 I don't have col-md-5/col-md-5

Comment: @Elikill58 I don't think you understood what I am trying to get at. I want block 2 to be centered in page and block1 to be on its left using bootstrap column so it is responsive.

Comment: Yes sorry, i misunderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using media queries without any bootstrap. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

@media (max-width:850px){
.mycontainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.myleft{
  order: 1;
  width: 97%;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  background-color: white;
}

.mymain{
  order: 2;
  width: 97%;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  background-color: white;
}

}


@media (min-width:850px){


.mycontainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.myleft{
  order: 1;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  background-color: white;
}

.mymain{
  order: 2;
  width: 60%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 1px solid #e9ecef;
}

}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="mycontainer">
      <div class="myleft">left column content</div>
      <div class="mymain">my main content</div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

To center the main column content you can just style it with css.

Comment: And here is info about how to create the left sidebar that stays there while scrolling: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_sidebar.asp

Comment: You are welcome. I have coded it for you: https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-MeyvVuvrZlRcUoCk9ZB the only trouble is that the content of the left column would have to be written there twice.. maybe you can insert it with php twice instead using include function.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can Use This Bootstrap Styling for create Responsive Column

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
          <div class="col-4">
          <p>Block-1 Left</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
          <p>Block-2 Right</p>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know how to create responsive columns in bootstrap. It is not the problem here. I want block 2 to be centered in page and block 1 to move as I scroll the page and on the left of block 1